# Copy file into multiple directories - Unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, directory, directory-structure

I want to copy one file into many directory. My path structure is like above.

```
folder1-> anotherfolder -> **here I want to copy my file**
folder2-> anotherfolder -> **here I want to copy my file**
folder3-> anotherfolder -> **here I want to copy my file**
folder4-> anotherfolder -> **here I want to copy my file**
```

folder1,2,3,4 is in the same directory. But the names are the folders are not sequential.

I can get the name of folders with this code but after that I don't know how can I get into the folders and copy my file.

```
    for d in */ ; do
     echo "$d"
    done
```

This code gives me the folders name in directory. After this step how can I get into folders and copy my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First try (has limitations)**

```
for d in $(find . -maxdepth 2 -type d | grep "/.*/"); do
    cp file "$d"
done
```

> LIMITATIONS:
>
> - No spaces/slashes/glob characters in the dir-names

**Second try (cleaner, thanks to gniourf_gniourf)**

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -path './*/*' -type d -exec cp file {} \;
```

Comment: I've edited the solution to catch only paths like ./folderA/folderB/

Comment: It copied but the file name changed into anotherfolder. My actual file name is test.java

Comment: Please, no! this is broken if directory name contains spaces or other funny characters (glob characters, etc.) Your use of `grep` also looks wrong.

Comment: I've added the Limitations section. Anyone wanting to come with a generic solution is welcome!

Comment: Since you're relying on `-maxdepth`, I can assume GNU `find` or similar that has the `-path` predicate: `find . -path './*/anotherfolder' -type d -exec cp file {} \;`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Could you please put your full working example, I think I miss some points when I try to your commands

Comment: The anotherfolder is a variable string!

Comment: This is the now full working command, thanks for both of you.

`find . -path './*/*' -type d -exec cp file {} \;`

Comment: It would still catch some deeper directories. One more adjustment: `find . -maxdepth 2 -path './*/*' -type d -exec cp file {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to do something like this:

```
for d in */; do
    cp file "$d"/anotherfolder
done
```